# Can we write python scripts through datastage sequence stage like execute command activity in 11.3 version?

Tags: python, datastage

I am trying to execute simple python script through command activity stage, but I am getting error as below:

sequence1..JobControl (@Execute_Command_4): Executed: python /home/mobaxterm/pyth.py
Reply=1
Output from command ====>
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Note : Version is Datastage 11.3 ( causing problem )

Suggest your views. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Seems like the PATH used does not fin python - try referenceing it with the whole path where python is installed on your system

Comment: Actually I am able to run the python script in unix but not able to run through datastage

Comment: If you run it natively it is using your own PATH settings - but running it through DataStage will run it under the DataStage user who does not necessarily have the same environment - test it using the full path ...

Comment: Path where I installed python is with windows path, so I am able to run the python through command prompt/bash. But dont know which path we need to give for python script to run through datastage,

Comment: Path : C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\

Comment: Do I need to copy everything of paython to the IBM path : C:\IBM\InformationServer\

Comment: No just specify the whole path c:\....\python /home/mobaxterm/pyth.py

Comment: I tried with full path.. But still the same issue I am getting. :(

Comment: Try to change/extend the PATH for the DataStage user (dsadm)

Comment: Can I share my screen with you ??

Answer (score -3):

you can use a OS script to call your python script